# chapter style in toc independent from page number style

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I changed the chapter entry style in the toc with `chapterentry` (in koma-script class document -- changing from koma-script is not an option) to small caps. Unfortunately this also effects the pages numbers for the chapter, i.e. the page numbers are small caps too. Is there a way to prevent the page numbers to be changed to small caps and just stay in the normal roman font?

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,              
    open=right,             
    twoside = true,
    paper=a4,               
    listof=totoc,       
    numbers=noenddot,
    headings=big,
    chapterprefix=false]    % 
{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily} 
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}     

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures                  
\listoftables   
\newpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\normalcolor}
```

to use the normal font for the chapter page numbers in the table of contents.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,              
    open=right,             
    twoside = true,
    paper=a4,               
    listof=totoc,       
    numbers=noenddot,
    headings=big,
    chapterprefix=false]    % 
{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily} 
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\normalcolor}%<- added
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures                  
\listoftables   
\newpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get what you want is to add the line

```
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\rmfamily\normalsize}
```

in your preambel.  Then the pagenumbers on the pages and in the toc are in the given font `\rmfamily` in size `\normalsize`.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt,              
  open=right,             
  twoside = true,
  paper=a4,               
  listof=totoc,       
  numbers=noenddot,
  headings=big,
  chapterprefix=false]    % 
{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily} 
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\rmfamily\normalsize} % <====================

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures                  
\listoftables   
\newpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

with the resulting toc:

[image]

Comment: `\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{...}` or `\setkomafont{pagenumber}{...}` affects only  page numbers in header or footer.